# Occupational Health Tag should be created

Tags: discussion

**Occupational Health** deals with hazards and diseases caused by the occupation of a person.
( Occupational Therapy is different from Occupational Health ). *Comments are invited* on the view - Should a separate tag for Occupational Health be created in the medical sciences section ?

Comment: We generally only create tags if there are enough questions in the tag that makes it worthwhile. Can you point to several questions where this tag would be useful above and beyond existing tags on those questions?